# Need references to understand/analyze a sentence for chatbot without using existing libraries

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, text-analysis

I tried to search a lot about this but all i could find was links to NLP libraries and AIML or chatbot APIs. I want to start from scratch and analyze the sentences myself so that i can write a basic chat bot that gives human like responses. Could someone please point to some links/research papers/ tutorials/videos for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using NLP libraries you'll have to write some of their functionality yourself. Although this can be educational you should know it can also be very time consuming.

Some academic resources:

- Christopher D. Manning's [Introduction to Information Retrieval](http://www-nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/)
- Manning/Jurafsky's [Speech and Language Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131873210)

Programming/practical resources:

- [How To Create Your Own Customised Chatbot For Beginners: Chatbots 101](https://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewthread/492/)
- [Be your own botmaster](http://www.alicebot.org/be.html)
- [NLTK book](http://www.nltk.org/book/) (although this is a library, the book and code base can be very educational)
- [Chatbot Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36106/Chatbot-Tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

As you're using AIML, you can get started simply by coding some patterns you would like to match. Imagine you wanted to analyse the simplest form of sentence in the form **subject verb object**. Using AIML v2 you could define sets for **subject**, **verb** and **object**. To keep things extremely simple the subject and object sets could contain simple objects (cat, dog, mouse, hat, mat, cheese) and the verb set could be things like eat, sat on etc. Your AIML would then be:

```
<category>
  <pattern> * <set>subject</set> <set>verb</set> * <set>object</set> </pattern>
  <template>
    <random>
      <li>I like <star index="2"/>s</li>
      <li>I hate <star index="2"/>s</li>
    </random>
  </template>
</category>
```

Input like "The cat sat on the mat" or "The dog ate the bone" would randomly produce output such as "I like cats", "I hate dogs" etc. Obviously you would need to greatly extend the template logic to analyse the sentence in a useful way.

Please note this is an extremely basic example, the aim is to show how AIML pattern matching enables you to get something going quickly, that can then be improved on.